# the nonexistence of a division algebra on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Prove that there is no division algebra structure on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$.

The hint says

> Suppose that there is such a structure on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$. Take a nonzero $a \in \mathbb R^{2n+1}$. Consider $f: S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{2n}, x \mapsto \frac{ax}{|ax|}$. Prove that $f$ and $-f$ are homotopic.

But how is this homotopy constructed? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find a path between $a$ and $-a$ that does not go through $0$.

Comment: Of course $n=0$ is excluded here.

Comment: Which is good, since $\mathbb R^1$ can be made into a division algebra pretty easily :) @GEdgar

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I think I know what to do now.